# Pixel collision detection in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I am creating a maze game in libGDX. The background texture is very similar to this one: http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/maze/maze_square_medium.png

My moving character is on the maze, and I would like to do collision detection between the character and black walls by checking the colour of my maze texture, without creating rectangles and figuring out all the coordinates of the maze walls, if that is possible. I have researched a lot, but since I am quite new to libGDX and even java, I haven't really found anything that made a lot of sense to me for my case. If anyone has an answer for me on how I could do this or can refer me to a page that explains this well, it would be very greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

This is my code right now:

```
private static final int COLS = 4;
private static final int ROWS = 4;
Sprite sprChar, sprMaze;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture Sprite;
TextureRegion[] frames;
TextureRegion CurrentFrame;
float fTime = 0f, fSpeed = 4;
Animation animation;
Texture txtMaze;
Pixmap pixmap;
int nX, nY, nPix, nR, nG, nB, nA;
Color color;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Sprite = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("snowwhite.png"));
    sprChar = new Sprite(Sprite);
    sprChar.setPosition(300, 200);
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(Sprite, Sprite.getWidth() / COLS, Sprite.getHeight(
    frames = new TextureRegion[COLS * ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            frames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    animation = new Animation(1f, frames);
    sprChar.setPosition(10, 10);
    pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("Maze2.png"));
    color = new Color();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    if (fTime < 4) {
        fTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    } else {
        fTime = 0;
    }

    nX = Math.round(sprChar.getX());
    nY = Math.round(sprChar.getY());
    nPix = pixmap.getPixel(nX, nY);
    Color.rgba8888ToColor(color, nPix);
    nR = (int) (color.r * 255f);
    nG = (int) (color.g * 255f);
    nB = (int) (color.b * 255f);
    nA = (int) (color.a * 255f);
    if (nR == 0 && nG == 0 && nB == 0) {
        System.out.println("is hit");
    }
    txtMaze = new Texture(pixmap);
    sprMaze = new Sprite(txtMaze);

    CurrentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
        sprChar.setX(sprChar.getX() - fSpeed);
        CurrentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(4 + fTime);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        sprChar.setX(sprChar.getX() + fSpeed);
        CurrentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(8 + fTime);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        sprChar.setY(sprChar.getY() + fSpeed);
        CurrentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(12 + fTime);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
        sprChar.setY(sprChar.getY() - fSpeed);
        CurrentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0 + fTime);
    }

    batch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.draw(sprMaze, sprMaze.getX(), sprMaze.getY(), sprMaze.getWidth() / 2,
            sprMaze.getHeight() / 2, sprMaze.getWidth(),
            sprMaze.getHeight(), sprMaze.getScaleX(),
            sprMaze.getScaleY(), sprMaze.getRotation());
    batch.draw(CurrentFrame, sprChar.getX(), sprChar.getY(), 20, 20);
    batch.end();
}

public static void updatePosition(Sprite spr, float fX, float fY) {
    spr.setPosition(fX, fY);
}
```

I just want it to output "is hit" if it passes a black wall, but I don't believe I am getting correct responses. Also, if I try to resize the maze sprite, it seems to me that it still checks for pixels on the maze at the original size.

P.S. Please excuse my bad code, I am VERY new. So any help would be very greatly appreciated, as I am on a time crunch!! Thank you

Comment: Load the maze image as a Pixmap. Use `getPixel()` on the pixmap to get the color of the pixel at that location, and then check the color of the returned integer.

Comment: When you say "at that location," does that mean I can only check the colour one pixel at a time? I was thinking maybe being able to use the coordinates of my character to check the colour, and if there is any black in it, return true, or something like that. But thank you very much for your help already!! Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yes, only one at a time. So check every pixel in the rectangle of your character.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: @Tenfour04 If you would look at my edit above, I would really appreciate it. I have some code now, but I don't believe it is working at all.

Comment: I don't have time to go through it now, but just want to point out, do not use the `new` keyword in the `render()` method, especially with a Disposable like a Texture. You are leaking a newly loaded copy of the Texture 60 times a second since you aren't disposing of it before losing the reference. And wasting time loading it repeatedly.

Comment: There's kind of too much here to explain all at once on this website. You are not yet up to speed on basic rendering or on physics, and using an image for hit detection is a combination of both concepts.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! I'll continue trying!